# How prevent some class properties from being returned from Web API?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm building a .NET Core Web API referencing a class library using Entity Framework Core.  We're database-first so will foreseeable be overwriting our data classes periodically to refresh them.

For e.g. an Employee object that has FirstName, LastName, but also Password, how can I prevent the Password attribute from being passed back with the object?

If I need to manipulate the data class, will I have to remember to manually re-edit every time I delete/re-create my data classes?  Thank you for any help!

Comment: Your exposed *View-Model* classes your API's serialize and pass should not be the same classes as your *Data Model* used by Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Data Transfer Objects (DTOs). Populate custom properties using a mapper and send it to the response. Also you can try this (Anonymous Types):

```
var employee = ...get from db;

return Ok(new
{
    employee.FirstName,
    employee.LastName
});
```

Comment: So depending what I want a calling client to access, I should basically create a new object (from the full one returned by my data context) and not include the attributes I don't want to expose?  I could do that but seems like a lot of plumbing.

Comment: Exactly, undertaking an architecture makes some difficulties but makes your code clean and maintainable. But you can use `Anonymous Types` without creating new objects as I have shown in the answer and use and Action Result Filter if you wanna have a clean code.